# Why can I not create a repo on github via hub create?

Tags: github, terminal, github-api

I am trying to create a repo on Github by running `hub create` in my terminal. I am not prompted to input any email or password for github in my terminal. When I run `hub create` the following error message is returned `Error creating repository: Unauthorized (HTTP 401) Bad credential`. I am really unsure of what to do. Is there a way to update my password locally? As I believe the problem may have been that I changed my password on the actual github website and now it does not match the password on my mac. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`hub create [-poc] [-d DESCRIPTION] [-h HOMEPAGE] [[ORGANIZATION/]NAME]`

Example:

````
[ repo created on GitHub ]
> git remote add -f origin git@github.com:USER/REPO.git

$ hub create sinatra/recipes
[ repo created in GitHub organization ]
> git remote add -f origin git@github.com:sinatra/recipes.git```
````

Comment: I tried this and this was the results ```Updating origin
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
error: Could not fetch origin ```

Comment: I guess i need to find out how out whether I have the correct access rights? Do you know how to do this?

Comment: first you have to check whether the repository is there or not. if the repository is not there please create that and try again. if the repository is there please again clone the repo and try again. thanks

Comment: how can I create the repository if both ```git remote add -f origin git@github.com:USER/REPO.git``` and ```hub create``` are not working